# Selecting SVGs in D3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I've got a little visualisation going where I have pairs of rectangles. Each pair shares the same id attribute. So currently, I've set it up so that if I hover over either one, both change colour. That's great, but, as I've done it, I need a new select("svg #whatever) command for each different pair. That can't be right.

So what I was thinking was setting up a variable, which would be the id of the element I was mousing over, then putting that inthe selct command, something like this

```
    svg.selectAll("rect")
.on("mouseover", function(d) {

var thisid = d3.select(this).attr("id")

     svg.selectAll("svg #"+thisid+)             
    .attr("fill", "red")
```

Except that doesn't work. Is it just the syntax - ie I've got the + + wrong -  or am I making a fundamental mistake here?

Comment: why not using a selector class instead of a selector id?

Comment: If you have more than one element with the same id then yes, you are making a fundamental mistake as your file is invalid.

Comment: Maybe I should use a selector class instead. I shall go off and find out about them. I'm not sure what you mean by invalid, though? It works, it's just a bit long winded.

Comment: But, regarding the original q. Maybe I expressed it wrong. Is there a way I can eg mouseover one element and make it do something to another element, with the selection of that element being based on some variable I could derive from the original element?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#IDAttribute (see how it says a **unique** name) and here in the XML specification http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-attribute-types If you violate the rules what you have may not work in different UAs or even different versions of the same UA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good, but as Robert Longson pointed out, you can't use `id` to link two related objects, since `id` has to be unique for the entire webpage.

You can, however, add any attribute you want to your data element (other than `id`) and preferably with an attribute name that starts `"data-"`, and then use a [CSS attribute selector](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/) to find other elements with the same attribute.  Like this:

```
//when you create the rectangles:
rect.attr("data-id", function(d) { 
                   return d.id;/* or however you figure out this id */
           });


//Your event handler
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {

      var thisid = d3.select(this).attr("data-id")

      svg.selectAll("svg rect[data-id='" + thisid + "']")
                 //note the single quotes inside double quotes 
                 //the final selector should look like "svg rect[data-id='23']" 
            .attr("fill", "red");

     });
```

The only downside it that  browsers don't index all attributes for fast access like they do with classnames and ids, so it could be slow if you had a large number of rectangles and mouse-over them rapidly.  Using a class would make selection faster, but adds a complication if you have multiple classes -- you can't just access the one class value you're interested in by calling `.attr("class")`.  You could, however, re-access whichever data variable you are using to define `data-id` in the first place.  Like this:

```
//when you create the rectangles:
rect.attr("data-id", function(d) { 
                   return "data-rectangle " + /* any other classes you are adding, + */
                        "data-id-" + d.id;/* or however you figure out this id */
           });


//Your event handler
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {

      var thisid = d.id; /* or however you figure out this id */
         //d3 automatically passed the element's data object to your event handler

      svg.selectAll("svg rect.data-id-" + thisid)
                 //the final selector should look like "svg rect.data-id-23" 
            .attr("fill", "red");

     });
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you. So I need to set up a key, basically? That's what I thought I would have to do then I thought maybe I could cheat with the ids....